# A Possible Bug with PDO's bindParam, bindValue and foreach

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue, bindparam

I have been getting an error with this code.

```
$Database = new Database('localhost','root','password','Db');    

$Statement = $Database->prepare("INSERT INTO User VALUES(:ID,:FirstName,:MiddleName:LastName,:RegisteredDate")

$Array_Bind = array(
'ID'=>$ID,
'FirstName'=>$FirstName,
'MIddeName'=>$MiddleName,
'LastName'=>$LastName
'RegisteredDate'=>$Date
)

foreach($Array_Bind AS $Key=>$value){
$Statement->bindParam(':' .$Key, $value)

}

if($Statement->execute()){
echo 'Successfully inserted into the database';


}else{
echo 'could not insert into database';
};
```

The following  have been noted  IF the $ID (PrimaryKey) is NOT by DEFAULT  an AUTO-INCREMENTING value in the MySQL Database.

1. ALL  Fields except DATETIME Fields gets the value of the last element in the array when inserted into the database.
   i.e.

   ID = $LastName
   FirstName = $LastName
   MiddleName = $LastName
   LastName = $LastName
   RegisteredDate = $RegisteredDate
2. The same error is outputted when bindValue is used.

So I ended up using

```
if($Statement->execute($Array_Bind)){
echo 'Successfully inserted into the database';


}else{
echo 'could not insert into database';
};
```

QUESTIONS

1. It is recommended to use  execute($array_Bind) assuming all data have been sanitize as against using bindParam or bindValue in this scenario?
2. If Not is there a way to use bindParam or bindValue  and arrays?
3. Is this a bug or wrong coding architecture.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed you had a typo in the placeholder name.  Don't know if this will sort the problem

```
$Statement = $Database->prepare("INSERT INTO User VALUES(:ID,:FirstName,:MiddleName:LastName,:RegisteredDate")

$Array_Bind = array(
'ID'=>$ID,
'FirstName'=>$FirstName,
'MIddeName'=>$MiddleName,
'LastName'=>$LastName
'RegisteredDate'=>$Date
)
```

You use a placeholder `MIddeName` but in your query you use `MiddleName`

Change this

```
'MIddeName'=>$MiddleName,
```

to this

```
'MiddleName'=>$MiddleName,
```

Comment: He's problem is far from that typo

Comment: At least it was a start

Comment: One don't need such a false start when case is clear and already solved.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check your premises. Then double check. Then check documentation.

- with bindParam it is not a bug but essential feature.
- with bindValue it never happen
- of course passing array into execute() is preferred, due to overall sanity and amount of code compared to other methods.